# How do I split a git repository(by branch)

Tags: git, branch, split

I started with a piece of code which got split into two small programs each in a different branch.

They share a lot of similarities but I'd like to split them into 2 repos so I can work on both at the same time in an easier fashion. It's annoying to have to commit a change(and get rid of/commit unimortant changes (such as gitignore and makefile flags)  before switching context before switching.

It's a pretty simple linear one person history except for that early split and a few unneeded stashes.
What's the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to just clone the repository, and possibly, delete the unneeded branch in the cloned repository.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler

```
mkdir program1
cd program1
git init
git pull ../origrepo smallprogram1
```

rinse, repeat

If you have stuff in a branch history that shouldn't be in that history any more, see `git-filter-branch` (e.g. `--index-filter 'git rm unwanted-bits'`) and you're good to go

Don't forget to vacuum on your way out (`git gc --prune=...` or `git repack`)